# Running Python test from Java error

Tags: java, python, eclipse, unit-testing

I'm trying to see if it is possible to run both PyTest suites and JUnit test suites from one place.
I have created a few simple projects as a mock up of the scenario I'm working with:
Project 1 = Python project with test-able outcome. Code:

```
def add(self):
    a = 1
    b = 2

     if (a + b) == 3:
         return True
     else:
         return False
```

Project 2 = Python project with pyTest module which tests Project 1. Code:

```
import unittest
from program import *

class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    def testProgram(self):

        self.assertTrue(add(self), 'The actual answer and the expected answer do not match')
        self.runTests()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testprogram']
    unittest.main()
```

Project 3 = Java project with a JUnit class which uses FileInputStream to copy and run the test module from Project 2. Code:

```
package project4;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class MTS2 {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
         PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();

        File src = new File(
                 "C:\\Users\\name\\workspaces\\project\\Workspace\\project2\\src\\TestProgram.py");
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(src);
        interp.execfile(is);
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Project 1 & 2 are in Project 3 as Referenced Projects.

Project 3 sort of works. It is definitely running Project 2 as the assertTrue  fail message I added to Project 2 comes up. However, the PyUnit test comes up as an Error even when the test should pass.

Console Error Message when test should pass:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: testProgram (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<iostream>", line 15, in testProgram
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'runTests'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

PyUnit Error:

```
============================= ERRORS =============================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\Workspaces\project\Workspace\project2\src\TestProgram.py", line 14, in testprogram
    self.assertTrue(add(self), 'The actual answer and the expected answer do not match')
AssertionError: The actual answer and the expected answer do not match

The AssertionError should not be happening as the test should pass.
```

Console error message when test should fail:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: testProgram (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<iostream>", line 14, in testProgram
AssertionError: The actual answer and the expected answer do not match

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.010s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

PyUnit error messages:

```
============================= ERRORS =============================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\Workspaces\project\Workspace\project2\src\TestProgram.py", line 14, in testprogram
    self.assertTrue(add(self), 'The actual answer and the expected answer do not match')
AssertionError: The actual answer and the expected answer do not match
```

Any help with working out what the problem is, or even a better way of running the Python test from Java, would be appreciated.

Comment: remove `self.runTests()`?

Comment: That gets rid of the AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'runTests' but I'm still getting an error when the test should pass.